# JS Using onSuccess() syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some code and I just see to be doing something wrong with the syntax.

Here is the code:

```
async mymethod(onSuccess, onFailure) {
    try {
        // Do some here
        onSuccess()
    }
    catch (e) {
        //this was an error
    }
}
```

What I want to do is its `onSuccess()` I want to do something.

Tried:

```
onSuccess((function() {
    // Do something
}))
```

But there seems to be a syntax error.

How do I use `onSuccess()` and do something with it?

Comment: Just put `// do something` just below `onSuccess()`?

Comment: When you call the async, you pass an anonymous function: `mymethod(function (data) { console.log(data); }, ...);` and inside, you just call whatever was passed, like `onSuccess(res.data);` https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/mrj7ugob/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `function` keyword:

```js
async function mymethod(onSuccess, onFailure) {
    try {
        // Do some here
        onSuccess()
    }
    catch (e) {
        //this was an error
        onFailure()
    }
}

mymethod(() => alert('success'), () => alert('failure'));
```

Comment: I'm using Typescript so I don't need the function

Comment: Does it work in TypeScript if you include `function`? Are you using this in a class? Have you got a full example demonstrating this?

Comment: Yes I'm using a class. I can do this onSuccess(console.log('something')) but I want to add multiple lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a typescript and a `class` you need to include the `public` access modifier as methods are `private` by default.

```
class Foo {
  public async mymethod(onSuccess, onFailure) {
    try {
      // Do some here
      onSuccess()
    }
    catch (e) {
      //this was an error
      onFailure()
    }
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.mymethod(() => { console.log('success') }, () => { console.log('failure') });
```